# When do we use keep + to inf and keep + ing?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

When do we use keep + to inf and keep + ing?
I searched on the internet and did not find anything really accurate and precise on the topic.

Comment: Apparently, we don't use *keep* with *to infinitive*, "keep to" would be a phrasal verb that should be followed by a noun or gerund.

Comment: That's right. "Keep" takes only a participial phrase, not an infinitive one.

Comment: Hopefully, if I still can help, I found a link that can help you. Basically, to+infintive---purpose. ing+gerund------remain the state. LINK: https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_different_list.htm

Comment: @Thunder05, what does it mean to **remain the state**?

Comment: @ohidano I refer to continue the action, remain the state of continuing of an action (take a look at the web I sent to you to understand better it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the verb **keep** with the present participle to emphasize that the ongoing action *persists* or *persisted* (or that it should persist, if the verb is in the imperative).

> I warned him to stop, but he **kept walking** out onto the thin ice.
>
> When you feel discouraged, **keep trying**.
>
> When long distance runners "hit the wall", they must summon the fortitude to **keep running**.
>
> At the theater, only a rude idiot **keeps talking** after the movie has begun.