# Extend vs Extending

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

We are also working with our customers as they make changes, including in sectors that are difficult to decarbonize, such as aviation, shipping, road freight, and industry. We will contribute to 'extend' the benefits of energy to everyone.

Should I use 'extend' or 'extending' in the above sentence?

Comment: For 'benefits' did you mean 'availability' or are you thinking of new uses for energy?

Comment: Yes, benefits means availability here

Comment: Then the whole sentence is in doubt, and there is no context.

Comment: I have provided the complete sentence

Comment: I would use 'extending' although I can't see any relation with the previous sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He continued to talk and he continued talking.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13215/) Also ['verb-ing' or 'to verb' after the verb 'continue'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26551/) and [Irregular usage of the verb “continue”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126229/) and [What's the difference between “continues doing” and “continues to do”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60898/) and [When do we use keep + to inf and keep + ing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119964/), among others.